# Проверить нажатие ctrl,shift в javascript

Tags: javascript

есть кусок кода, выполняется в цикле.
в нем надо проверить нажата ли одна из клавиш ctrl или shift.
по событиям не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Браузерный JS - не слишком многопоточный язык. Пока ваш цикл не закончит выполнение - глобальное состояние не поменяется.

Самый простой вариант - прерывать цикл раз в несколько итераций, и ставить оставшиеся итерации на выполнение через `window.setTimeout`, чтобы глобальные события отработали. В глобальных событиях ловить нажатие shift, например как

```
var shiftDown = false;
var setShiftDown = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 16 || event.charCode === 16){
        window.shiftDown = true;
    }
};

var setShiftUp = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 16 || event.charCode === 16){
        window.shiftDown = false;
    }
};

window.addEventListener? document.addEventListener('keydown', setShiftDown) : document.attachEvent('keydown', setShiftDown);
window.addEventListener? document.addEventListener('keyup', setShiftUp) : document.attachEvent('keyup', setShiftUp);
```

Comment: а просто прочитать "регистр клавы"? event ведь чтото счтывает...

Comment: эвенту приходит готовое событие от системы, с конкретным кодом нажатой кнопки.

Comment: судя по минусу, кто-то знает как прочитать "регистр клавы"? :)